# Polygon featureadded callback on custom control openlayers

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

Hi is there a way to have a callback after a polygon is added on a certain layer? The scenario is I added a custom control on my map and this control will call a draw polygon interaction. Now I would like to have a callback that helps me find out that the drawing of polygon is already added. Right now my code is as below

```
var polysource = new ol.source.Vector({wrapX: false});
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: id,
    controls: ol.control.defaults()
        .extend([
            new ol.control.FullScreen(),
            new windowpoly.DrawPolygon()
        ]),
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        }),
        new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: polysource
        })
    ],
    loadTilesWhileAnimating: true,
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [0,0],
        zoom: 11
    })
});

// Create a custom control for the drawpolygon
var windowpoly = {};
windowpoly.DrawPolygon = function(opt_options) {

    var options = opt_options || {};

    var button = document.createElement('button');
    button.innerHTML = '/';

    var this_ = this;
    var drawPolygon = function(e) {
        addInteraction();
    };

    button.addEventListener('click', drawPolygon, false);
    button.addEventListener('touchstart', drawPolygon, false);

    var element = document.createElement('div');
    element.className = 'draw-polygon ol-unselectable ol-control';
    element.appendChild(button);

    ol.control.Control.call(this, {
        element: element,
        target: options.target
    });

};
ol.inherits(windowpoly.DrawPolygon, ol.control.Control);

// Function to initialize draw polygon
function addInteraction()
{
    draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
        source: polysource,
        type: /** @type {ol.geom.GeometryType} */ ('Polygon')
    });
    map.addInteraction(draw);
}
```

Now what I want is after I draw the polygon an ajax call will be triggered. But I don't know how to add the featureadded callback on a custom control. I'm using Openlayers 3 for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the source to the control in opt_options and then have the control listen to "addfeature".

```
source.on('addfeature', function(feature) {
        // do something with the feature 
    }, this);
```